# Magento 2: db_schema_whitelist.json

Tags: magento2, json, whitelist

What is the main usage of db_schema_whitelist.json file ?

Answer (score 1):

In the simple term: "**db_schema_whitelist.json file is a history of all tables, columns, and keys** added with the declarative schema."

With the release of **Magento 2.3** Declarative Schema files declare what the database structure should be.

For more understanding go to this [link](https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-db-schema-whitelist-json-in-magento-2/).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 versions from 2.3 have a replacement for traditional install/upgrade schema which is used to maintain the database structure.

From Magento 2 version 2.3, they have introduced the declarative schema file for database (etc/db_schema.xml) which is used to maintain the database structure for a module.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

The db_schema_whitelist. json file is a way of telling Magento which tables and columns it can safely alter using the db_schema. xml file. It was added to preserve backward compatibility and will be removed in a future version when the install/upgrade script be no longer supported.

```
[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258407/magento-2-3-use-of-db-schema-whitelist-json-file-in-etc-directory-of-each-modu#:~:text=The%20db_schema_whitelist.,script%20be%20no%20longer%20supported.][1]
```